# Removing oldest 10 rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need a MySQL statement to remove the oldest 10 entries from my table, however the closest I can get is this:

```
   DECLARE ID INT;
   SET ID = (SELECT CallbackID FROM callbacks ORDER BY CallbackID LIMIT 1 OFFSET 9);

   DELETE FROM callbacks WHERE callbackID <= ID;
```

which is fine if there were always at least 10 entries, but when there are less, the ID is not set and therefore the delete statement fails.

Any ideas?
Thanks

EDIT: 
Tried this too:

```
   DECLARE ID INT;
   SET ID = (SELECT CallbackID FROM callbacks ORDER BY CallbackID LIMIT 1 OFFSET 9);

   if ID IS NOT NULL THEN

   DELETE FROM callbacks WHERE callbackID <= ID;
   END IF;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
DELETE FROM callbacks ORDER BY CallbackID LIMIT 10;
```

[Yeah, it works `:)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/delete.html)

Comment: The OP wants to order by date, so presumably an `ORDER BY [date column] DESC` would sit nicely at the end of the query?

Comment: @mimitech Wouldn't you want to `ORDER BY ... DESC`, not `ASC` ?

Comment: @njk: No; the oldest ones will have the lowest ID. Or so I'm assuming. It just does the same thing as the original query.

Comment: @minitech Sorry, I didn't see that there. A tired mind often misses the most obvious things.

Comment: Limit is unsupported in some versions of MySQL unfortunately

Comment: @minitech That part is slightly confusing. I'm using "oldest 10 entries" requirement.

Comment: @Jon: Are you sure you're using MySQL? `ORDER BY` is only supported after version 4.0.0, but it looks like `LIMIT` has always been supported...

Comment: @njk: I take it `callbackID` is some kind of incrementing ID. It wouldn't make sense for it to grow *downwards*.

Comment: It may work actually, but I am not sure I am comfortable disabling safe mode, which is what is is moaning about:

"You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column"

callbackID is an incrementing ID yes.

Comment: Ah that's better thank you. It seems to be working great now!

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM callbacks 
WHERE callbackID in (
    SELECT CallbackID 
    FROM callbacks 
    ORDER BY CallbackID LIMIT 10
)
```

Comment: Tried that, but Limit is unsupported in some versions of MySQL unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM callbacks ORDER BY callbackID DESC LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1):

After the `SET`, you only need an if statement that checks if the `ID` is set, if yes do query, else do something else or nothing.

Comment: IF ( something> 0) THEN 
   SELECT .. FROM app_user WHERE id=1
END IF;

or am i compleetly out of the picture ?

Comment: So put that in your answer - that's what makes it a complete answer :)

Comment: That was a good answer and didn't require a downvote. Thanks user I tried that (See my edited answer). Unfortunately it moand about safe mode and didn't do anything!